# git: export from bitbucket and import github (w/ commits)

Tags: ruby, git, github, bitbucket

I created a private git repo on bitbucket and committed code.
Now I want to export all (commits, code, history) and import it in a git repo on github.

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [move git repository with all branches from bitbucket to github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906917/move-git-repository-with-all-branches-from-bitbucket-to-github)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Check everything out locally to your computer and git pull.
2. Create a github repo
3. Add this repo as your second remote ("with git remote add github URL")
4. Push to the second remote

Comment: exactly, however I did have to git pull before. And then git push --force. Thanks again

Comment: Np, I am sure there are better ways, this is just the first to come to mind :-)