# move git pull requests from bitbucket to github?

Tags: git, pull-request

My client was using Bitbucket for his git repo, I made a lot of work, created many pull requests in it, but recently he moved his repo to Github without my pull requests.

How I can move pull requests to copied Github repo?

I saw that post: [How to move git repository with all branches from bitbucket to github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906917/how-to-move-git-repository-with-all-branches-from-bitbucket-to-github), but over there they discuss moving the repo itself with everything else, but in my case I just need to move pull requests only.

Answer (score 10):

One simple option is to:

- fork that new GitHub repo into your own account
- clone that fork (that you own)
- add as a git remote a reference to the BitBucket repo (which might have a different history, different sha1)

  ```
  git remote add bitbucket https://bitbucket.org/account/repo
  git fetch bitbucket
  ```
- create a local branch (git checkout -b mypatch)
- [**cherry-pick** the commits of the `bitbucket/yourBranch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309) (with yourBranch being the branch where you were doing patches for your BitBucket pull request).
  That will replay the commits of your BitBucket patch branch onto your new local branch.
- push that new local branch to your GitHub fork
- trigger a new pull request from that newly pushed branch.

Comment: Hi, I found this insightful, I am moving to github, wondering if there is an option to save this and run it from _nside_ github, since they now have import repo option directly. Also, this step seems to be the key to having two repo reference in one folder, " _add as a git remote a reference to the BitBucket repo (which might have a different history_ " can you please expand how to do this