# Move a github folder into a new repo with all the branches and history

Tags: git, github

I have a  repo-a in github with many folders (f1, f2, f3). 
I want to create a new repo (repo-b) with f1, with all the branches.

```
Repo-a
 |_ f1
 |_ f2  ------+ 
 |_ f3        |
              |  Copy folder with branches and history 
Repo-b        |
 |_ f2  <-----+
```

This is what am i doing, but it only pushes one branch:

1. clone the original repo

   git clone https://github.com/myuser/repo-a
2. now remove everything but the folder i need

   git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter f2 -- --all
3. then i change the remote origin to the new rep

   git remote set-url origin https://github/myuser/repo-b
4. and finally i push everything

   git push --all origin

As i stated, when i check on repo-b it only contains one branch and not all of them.

Any ideas ??

Thanks.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it fails on point 5. (git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter \
 YOUR_FOLDER_NAME master). any idea? it says 'bad revision'

Answer (score -1):

The answer to a previous question details how to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22907155/3566042

In short, see GitHub's documentation at https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/

> To create a duplicate of a repository without forking, you need to run a special clone command against the original repository and mirror-push to the new one.

Otherwise, you can fork the first Github repo.

Comment: Could the voter comment on why this was downvoted once?

Comment: the post you mention only explain how to mirror a repo. What i want to do is mirro only a folder from a repo.